# python multiprocess - launching jobs on availble slots

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm launching jobs on a server.

The server can process only one job at a time

So, I use the trick of using several user accounts on the server : userA , userB , userC , userD

for the moment I launch job with a function

```
run_job_on_server(some_args , user_name)
```

my question is quite simple : how can , using multiprocess (or another module), launch many jobs using the different users available, and when a job finished, make the user re-available and immediately after launch a new job with this user

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Typical approach would be to use queue to gather requests and then handle them. Or to use something like Celery: http://www.celeryproject.org .

Comment: Which part of [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) isn't clear?

Answer (score 0):

I think your question goes into the library selection (multiprocessing) too quickly. The first thing to do is to establish the design pattern. As a start, I think you could look at the dispatcher or mailbox pattern, and the active object pattern.

As for libraries, you're not stuck with the python standard lib. pip has many nice options too. I personally love ZeroMQ for distributed systems, but that's step two. Maybe the standard lib like Queue and multiprocessing will do.